# Why didn't the text come out?

Tags: android-layout

I have created the recommended modules and comments for the student competencies database. But what's wrong, why did it not appear?

Here is the screenshot for this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugwYw.png)

1. DatabasehelperCompetencies.java
2. LearnerInformation.java
3. RecommendedModule.java

I got the code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null) {
        id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        loginName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        studentName = intent.getStringExtra("studentName");
        Competencies = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        Answer1 = intent.getStringExtra("answer1");
        Answer2 = intent.getStringExtra("answer2");
        Answer3 = intent.getStringExtra("answer3");
        Answer4 = intent.getStringExtra("answer4");
        RecommendedModule = intent.getStringExtra("recommendedModule");
        StudentComments = intent.getStringExtra("studentComments");
    }

    getId = Integer.parseInt(id);
    login_Name.setText(loginName);
    studentname.setText(studentName);
    competencies.setText(Competencies);
    answer1.setText(Answer1);
    answer2.setText(Answer2);
    answer3.setText(Answer3);
    answer4.setText(Answer4);
    recommendedModule.setText(RecommendedModule);
    comments.setText(StudentComments);
```

Comment: Please post more details: xml layout, code which sets the text

Comment: This is the code

Comment: It's look likes your above code isn't related with how the data is created and passed. Btw, you should send the whole data as a pojo instead of sending each item with different keys.